# JavaScript Advanced Object Keys

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-os

I'm making a Chrome app that requires advanced Object.keys() that I can't seem to find anywhere. Here's some of my code.

```
Dictionary = {
  C: {
    "calculation": {"definitions":["a process or result of calculating 
    something.", "careful thought and planning that is done usually for 
    selfish reasons.]}
  },

  Search: function(word) {
    var foundWordInfo = {Word:null, Definitions:[]};
    var allDictionaryKeys = Object.keys(Dictionary);
    var firstLetter = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    var letterIndex = allDictionaryKeys.indexOf(firstLetter);

    var wordKeys = Object.keys(Dictionary[firstLetter]);
    for(i=0; i<wordKeys.length; i++) {
      if (wordKeys[i] == word) {
        foundWordInfo.Word = wordKeys[i];
        break;
      } else {}
    }

    return foundWordInfo;
};
```

The way it works is you use

```
var search = Dictionary.Search("calculation");
```

where the search variable is equal to the Dictionary.Search foundWordInfo object.

The search variable does return the word but the definitions always return as either undefined or null. I've tried things like

```
var definitions = wordKeys[i].Definitions;
```

and

```
var definitions = Dictionary[letterIndex][wordKeys[i]].Definitions;
```

but nothing I've used so far works. I'd prefer something like

```
var definitions = wordKeys[i].Definitions;
```

but as of right now I'll use what I can get. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You’re looking for `var definitions = Dictionary[firstLetter][wordKeys[i]].Definitions` (`firstLetter`, not `letterIndex`). This is a bit of an awkward data structure, though, and it’s mixed with behaviour. How about separating the search function out and making `Dictionary`’s values arrays?

Comment: I guess it's worth a shot. I'll try it.

Comment: I just realized that I can't. I need each letter in Dictionary to be objects so that I can store the word with it's data. Making it into an array would mean that I could only store one value per word which means I would not be able to add multiple definitions to a word.

Comment: It would be an array of objects. `{word: 'calculation', definitions: …}`

Answer (score 0):

You can access the word `definitions` using `Dictionary[firstLetter][wordKeys[i]].definitions`

```js
var Dictionary = {
  C: {
    "calculation": {"definitions":["a process or result of calculating something.", "careful thought and planning that is done usually for selfish reasons."]}
  },

  Search: function(word) {
    var foundWordInfo = {Word:null, Definitions:[]};
    var allDictionaryKeys = Object.keys(Dictionary);
    var firstLetter = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    var wordKeys = Object.keys(Dictionary[firstLetter]);
    for(i=0; i< wordKeys.length; i++) {
      if (wordKeys[i] == word) {
        foundWordInfo.Word = wordKeys[i];
        foundWordInfo.Definitions = Dictionary[firstLetter][wordKeys[i]].definitions;
        break;
      } else {}
    }
    return foundWordInfo;
}
}
var search = Dictionary.Search("calculation");
console.log(search);
```

Alternatively, you can do like this.

```js
var Dictionary = {
  C: {
    "calculation": {"definitions":["a process or result of calculating something.", "careful thought and planning that is done usually for selfish reasons."]}
  },

  Search: function(word) {
    var foundWordInfo = {Word:null, Definitions:[]};
    var firstLetter = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    foundWordInfo.Word = Object.keys(Dictionary[firstLetter]).find(function(key) {
      return key === word;
    }) || null;
    if(foundWordInfo.Word)
      foundWordInfo.Definitions = Dictionary[firstLetter][word].definitions;
    return foundWordInfo;
}
}
var search = Dictionary.Search("calculation");
console.log(search);
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a lifesaver. It works perfectly. This issue is solved.